# what is the reason for this constructor/destructor behaviour in php?

Tags: php

I'm running a simple constructor/destructor program in PHP

why is the output beginning with the two lines

**created dog 0

created dog 1**

when it should be

**created dog 0

destroyed dog 0**

```
<?php

class dog{

    public $name;

    public function __construct($name){

        $this->name = $name;
        echo "created dog $name <br/>";

    }
    public function __destruct()
    {

        echo "destroyed dog $this->name <br/>";
    }

}

for($i = 0;$i<=2;$i++)
{

    $dog = new dog($i);

}


$dog = new dog("last");

?>
```

full output

```
created dog 0 
created dog 1 
destroyed dog 0 
created dog 2 
destroyed dog 1 
created dog last 
destroyed dog 2 
destroyed dog last
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting at the first iteration of the for loop.  Behind the scenes, there is a space in memory allocated to hold a Dog() object.

Then a new variable `$dog` is assigned the pointer/reference to the Dog()'s address in memory.  We see the first created message.

Now as we know, that first Dog() will only be destroyed when there are no more references to it.

Bearing that in mind, the second time through the loop, the same process is repeated.  A new space in memory is allocated to a new Dog(), and then the address of that memory is given to `$dog` again.  Second create message.

Now the original dog has no references pointing to it, so it can be destroyed.  First destroy message.

Follow that same process and you should see why the rest of the messages read out as they do.

Comment: according to your solution, in the last loop iteration `destroyed dog 2` should occur before `created dog last` because all references of the objects created in the loop are destroyed as soon as the for loop is exited. so why does PHP delay the call to `destroyed dog 2` till after `created dog last`

Comment: PHP doesn't create a new variable scope when you're in a `for` loop and so there's no reason for the last object created in the loop to lose its references / be destroyed.  `Destroyed dog 2` follows the loss of the reference to the `dog 2` object.  The creation and assignment of the `last` dog (which triggers the `created dog last` first) is what forced that reference to be lost.  So the creation of the last dog precedes the check for any more references to `dog 2`.  It's all about the variable assignment, and nothing to do with scope in your example code.  Sorry if I didn't make that clear.